# ERROR running force:org:create: MultiLevelMasterDetail is not a valid Features value

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, spring-20, scratch-org-definition-file

Thought i'd post this here given we are no longer in the preview window, whenever I request the [MultiLevelMasterDetail feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) in my scratch org definition file. Im greeted with

`"ERROR running force:org:create:  MultiLevelMasterDetail is not a valid Features value."`

My Devhub is on Spring '20 Patch 10.4 and i'm running the latest version of sfdx on my mac.

Version: sfdx-cli/7.47.0-0e5d18732f darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3

```
{
  "orgName": "Buy Ethereum", 
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features":["MultiLevelMasterDetail"]
}
```

Comment: Do you have the most recent version of the CLI?

Comment: Believe so i'm running 7.47.0-0e5d18732f

Comment: Really weird... This looks like a known issue. if I were you, I would open a case with Salesforce. I have the most recent CLI version and still get the same error.

Comment: That was also my initial assumption, thought I'd post it up incase I'd overlooked the obvious! I will leave it a few hours just incase someone has an epiphany or is able to confirm it as an issue. Failing that I will raise it with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating with the below command:

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a multi-level-org
```

the definition file is

```
{
"orgName": "Multi Level org",
"edition": "Developer",
"hasSampleData": false,
"settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
        "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "securitySettings": {
        "passwordPolicies": {
            "enableSetPasswordInApi": true
        }
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
        "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
},
"features": ["MultiLevelMasterDetail"]
}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me.

Comment: Agreed this doesn't work for me either, @Abhijith out of curiosity are you running the latest version of sfdx? 

If you type sfdx into the terminal it should print you the version number directly underneath.

Comment: not sure why... the version i am using is: sfdx-cli/7.46.3 darwin-x64 node-v10.16.0

Comment: Can you run an update and try again?

Comment: @Crispy, did you reach out to SF on this? Any luck?

Comment: I have raised a case for this within my org - awaiting response

Comment: hey, guys, it is not working for me either :(

Comment: @Crispy any news from support?

Comment: I've been pointed at sfdx documentation, apparently it won't be passed onto tech support as I do not have Premier support. Like borat would say it was great success. I have been advised to try the developer forums even though i linked to this post on the case. Think I'll just raise an issue direct on github, should have thought of that earlier!